# How & when did Lord Shiva had started to wear tiger skin?

Tags: shiva, shiva-purana

Does Shiva purana have any story which describes about when did Shiva had started to wear tiger skin or when & how he started to hold trishul & damru?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are Gods and Yogis shown sitting on animals skins?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/295/why-are-gods-and-yogis-shown-sitting-on-animals-skins)

Comment: the question is about whether there is any story mentioned in Shiva purana... @CR241